# How to create an ASP.NET Listview with draggable column widths?

Tags: asp.net, listview, width, asp.net-3.5, columnheader

In windows applications we can change the `ListView`'s column width by just dragging the header of the column. How can I done that in a ASP.NET `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET listview does not support that feature. You can make your own implementation using a combination of ASP.NET and Javascript (or ASP.NET AJAX or JQuery).

Comment: Is there any samples or tutorials available?

Comment: Just search "AJAX table grid". There are many products but mostly for a fee. If you know JavaScript well, you can write your own.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the [Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx).

Specifically check out the demos for:

1. [Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx)
2. [ListView](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/listview.aspx)

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Grid/) also makes some great control packages as well that might suit your needs.  I haven't come across very many great 'free' ajax enabled grid controls that I would recommend unfortunately.

You can also look on the [ASP.NET site](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/browse.aspx?category=25) for a list of controls.